# Error referencing DLL in C# "A reference to xxx.DLL could not be added

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to reference a DLL in a C# application. The DLL has been written in C++. To make the reference I am right-clicking on the "references" section on the solution explorer and choosing "Add Reference" and then browsing to it. Every time I try, I get an error message

> A reference to xxx.DLL could not be added. Please make sure that the
>   file is acessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Having done some googling, I noted that many people suggest using TlbImp.exe to get a valid DLL, but when I run it at the command line, I get,

> TlbImp:error TI0000 : The input file xxx.dll is not a valid type
>   library.

It did occur to me that the DLL in question might just be badly written (the chap who wrote it is now on holiday) so I worked through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms235636.aspx) microsoft walkthrough to create a new, very simple dll, and I got the same result.

I am using VS2015, although I did previously have an install of VS2013 Express. I also tried the same process on another machine with VS2013 and VS2010. The effects were the same.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the DLL is not a COM server and has an export based interface that should be called via p/invoke rather than via a COM reference. (Just like the sample you linked to)

Comment: You can add reference to the another .NAT assembly or to the COM. To use native DDLs you need to use P/Invoke

Comment: See [What are Native DLLs? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995564/what-are-native-dlls/16625127) and [windows - Correct name for non-COM, non-.NET DLL? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564079/correct-name-for-non-com-non-net-dll/17384750#17384750). People say "DLL" and that is very confusing since it is ambiguous. There are many types of DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your dll in your project then embedd it as a resource, and choose to copy it to output directory if newer or always: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/508eb96ae4b047ba54db4e47/t/519e1809e4b01e6a03d7f51b/1369315338280/properties.png?format=750w

Then use platform invoke:

```
[DllImport("nameofyourdll.dll")]
public static extern void methodnameinyourdll(string param1, string param2);
public static void Main() 
{
    methodnameinyourdll("test1", "test2");
}
```

Sometimes you may have to use native types but they are not compatible with CLR to avoid that use Marshalling:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/66245/marshaling-with-csharp-chapter-1-introducing-marsh.aspx